# how to place mat-form-field and mat-chip-list in the same line?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to display one input field and one chip item side by side. But, chip is going to the next line. Is there any way I can place them side by side in the same row?

Current position:

[image: Current position]

Expected position:

[image: Expected position]

Comment: Try using `display: flex` on their parent wrapper.

Comment: try display:inline-block on mat-form-field and mat-chip-list

Comment: Is the bottom image what you are wanting to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

Try using below css on the div container..

```
.div-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I happen to get it with below:  `display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: Wow, very nice!! Keep it up

Comment: I used `display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: center;`